# .htaccess advanced multiple subdomain rewrite all-in-one folder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to archive multiple subdomains in one root folder, for domain.com/xxxx?xxx&xx its working no problems, but as soon as i try to bring subdomains in I always run in that nasty i guess it was 403 error...

So here's the thing:
I want to connect all subdomains exact the same as the normal domain,
also it should be all-in-one .htaccess file...

the structure looks like this:

`https://example.com/index.php?path=$1&content=$2`

for my subdomains i also need,

`https://admin.example.com/index.php?path=$1&content=$2`

`https://support.example.com/index.php?path=$1&content=$2`

so if you go **admin.example.com/tksys/** it should result in **admin.example.com/index.php?&path=tksys&content=$2** and should load from folder **/admin/tksys/main.php ($2)** my php catches the path like this...

`$path = isset($_GET['path']) && !empty($_GET['path']) ? $_GET['path'] : 'main';`

Folder structure:

```
/admin/
/admin/index.php
/admin/main.php
/admin/tksys/
/admin/tksys/main.php
/admin/tksys/viewall.php
/support/
/support/index.php
/support/main.php
/support/faq/
/support/faq/main.php
/support/ticket/
/support/ticket/main.php
/support/ticket/create.php
```

### HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
FallbackResource index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#SITES
RewriteRule ^beta/?$ tpl/index.php?path=main [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^beta/logout logout.php [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^beta/(main|news|games|settings)/?$ tpl/index.php?path=$1&content=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^beta/user/?$ tpl/index.php?path=user&content=main [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^beta/user/(.+?)/?$ tpl/index.php?path=user&content=main&user=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^beta/news/?$ tpl/index.php?path=news&content=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^beta/games/?$ tpl/index.php?path=games&content=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^beta/settings/?$ tpl/index.php?path=settings&content=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^oauth2/(twitch|steam)?$ oauth2/$1.php [NC,L]

#ADMIN
RewriteRule ^(tksys|usrsys|threads|status)/?$ index.php?path=$1&content=$2 [NC,L]

#SUPPORT
RewriteRule ^(helpdesk|faq|ticket)/?$ index.php?path=$1&content=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^helpdesk/?$ index.php?path=helpdesk&content=$2 [NC,L]

#ERRORs
ErrorDocument 401 /error/401
#ErrorDocument 402 /error/402
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404
#ErrorDocument 405 /error/405
#ErrorDocument 406 /error/406
#ErrorDocument 407 /error/407
#ErrorDocument 408 /error/408
#ErrorDocument 409 /error/409
#ErrorDocument 410 /error/410
#ErrorDocument 411 /error/411
#ErrorDocument 412 /error/412
#ErrorDocument 413 /error/413
#ErrorDocument 414 /error/414
#ErrorDocument 415 /error/415
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500
#ErrorDocument 501 /error/501
#ErrorDocument 502 /error/502
#ErrorDocument 503 /error/503
#ErrorDocument 504 /error/504
#ErrorDocument 505 /error/505


#Disable Directory Listing

IndexIgnore *
```

If i miss anything please let me know and i will add it.

Thanks for taking time,
have a nice day

Comment: Do you have subdomains as alias in apache config? also what are you trying to catch here `content=$2`? You current rules looks like that will be empty.

Comment: hi, what do you mean as alias....?
and its complete ok if $2 is empty ... no worry about that :)